# Division of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $a,b$ are distinct real numbers , then the remainder in the division of $f(x)$ by $(x-a)(x-b)$ is

$(a)$ $ ((x-a)*f(a)-(x-b)*f(b))/(a-b) $

$(b)$ $ ((x-a)*f(b)-(x-b)*f(a))/(b-a) $

$(c)$ $((x-a)*f(b)-(x-b)*f(a))/(a-b) $

$(d)$ $((x-a)*f(a)-(x-b)*f(b))/(b-a) $

My attempt - My attempt has largely been feeble . In fact using basic division theorem till now , I have only been able to identify that $f(a) = r(a)$ and $f(b) = r(b)$. Since if we use the division algorithm with $ x=a $ and $ x=b $ we could easily determine this.

Comment: Funny thing is, I had this problem in my first year's first semester exam. Let me give you a hint. The remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-a)(x-b)$ must be a polynomial with real coefficients of degree at most $1$ (why), so suppose that $r(x)=px+q$ where $p,q$ are reals. Now, try to solve for $p,q$ using $r(a)=f(a)$ and $r(b)=f(b)$.

Comment: We are looking for a polynomial $R(x)$ of degree at most $1$ such that $R(a)=f(a)$ and $E(b)=f(b)$. Since they have kindly supplied possible answers, all we need to do is plug in and see which works.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, shortcuts aren't nice when there's a way to solve this without the options. ;)

Comment: Definitely agree, and would add that multiple choice questions are not nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first note that the reminder of division of f(x) on x-a is f(a). The proof is very simple:
f(x)=fa(x)(x-a)+ r(a)
Applying x=a, 
f(a) =fa(a)(a-a) +r(a)
r(a)=f(a)

Then f(x) =fa(x)(x-a) + f(a)

Where fa(x) = (f(x)- f(a)) /(x-a)

Now 
fa(x)=fab(x)(x-b) + fa(b)

From the previous equation,

fa(b) = (f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)

Finally

f(x) = fab(x)(x-a)(x-b) + (f(b)-f(a))(x-a)/(b-a) + f(a)

The last two terms is the reminder

Multiplying the last term by (b-a)/(b-a) we arrive at

(f(b)(x-a) - f(a)(x-a) + f(a)(b-a))   / (b-a) =

= (f(b)(x-a) - f(a)(x-b))/(b-a)